# A problem about center of mass

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, integral-inequality

Suppose $f(x)$ is positive, increasing and Riemann-integrable on the interval $[a,b]$. Let$$\bar{x}=\frac{\int_a^b xf(x)\,\text{d}x}{\int_a^b f(x)\,\text{d}x}.$$Prove that$$\int_a^{\bar{x}} f(x)\,\text{d}x \le \int_{\bar{x}}^b f(x)\,\text{d}x.$$I tried the mean value theorem, but failed to reach the conclusion. Can anyone give a hint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us reduce the question to a known result. Replacing $f$ with $(\int_a^bf)^{-1}f$ if necessary,we may, (and will), suppose without loss of generality that $\int_a^bf=1$.

For every convex function $\varphi$ we have by [Jensen's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality)
$$\varphi\left(\int_a^b xf(x) dx\right)\leq \int_a^b\varphi(x)f(x)dx$$
or, using the notation of the problem:
$$\varphi\left(\bar{x}\right)\leq \int_a^b\varphi(x)f(x)dx$$
Now, since $f$ is increasing then $\varphi:[a,b]\to\Bbb{R}:\varphi(x)=\int_a^xf(t)dt$ is convex, and consequently, we can apply the previous inequality with this $\varphi$:
$$\int_a^{\bar{x}}f(t)dt\leq \int_a^b\left(\int_a^xf(t)dt\right)f(x)dx
=\left.\frac{1}{2}\left(\int_a^xf(t)dt\right)^2\right\vert_{x=a}^{x=b}=\frac{1}{2}$$
and the desired inequality follows since
$$\int_a^{\bar{x}}f(t)dt+\int_{\bar{x}}^bf(t)dt=1$$
the desired inequality follows.$\qquad\square$

Comment: But your function decreases on [0,1].

Comment: Yes, I didn't see this hypothesis, Now the result is correct, and I gave a proof of it.